# How is data transferred from memory to PCIe cards?

Tags: dma, pci-e

My question is about data transfer between a PCIe peripherial and system memory. Example:
Suppose we need to send a big chunk of data ( stored in system memory ) over an Ethernet network.

How will it usually be done ? 
Will the Ethernet card's controller have to request the data via "Bus Mastering" ( after being programmed by the CPU to do so ) ? 
Or will a centralized DMA controller near the CPU just write the card's buffers ( after being programmed by the CPU to do so ) ?

In other words:
Does the card have to ask for the data ? Or can it simply be written to it via the CPU's DMA ?

Comment: Usually Ethernet card has its own DMA engine.

Answer (score -1):

PCIe bulk data transfers are generally performed by the device, using bus mastering, as you guessed.

In your question, you imply that having a separate DMA device do the transfer is simpler than having the device do it, but I think the opposite--it is simpler for the device to do it.

Comment: So if a CPU wants to send data over Ethernet:
1. The CPU makes sure the data is arranged in memory.
2. The CPU sends an interrupt to the Ethernet card's controller to let it know the data is there.
3. The Ethernet card's controller reads data via bus mastering and sends it away over the network.

Is this the process ?